# Automorphisms of semidirect product of groups with characteristic factor

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, automorphism-group

Let $G = H \rtimes K$ be a group and let $H$ be characteristic in $G$.
This way for every $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ there is a restriction $\phi'\in\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ given by
$$
\phi' = \phi\big\rvert_H. 
$$
There is also a factor automorphism $\bar\phi\colon G/H \rightarrow G/H$.

I wonder wether for every $(h,k)\in G$ holds
$$
\phi\big( (h,k) \big) = \big( \phi'(h), \bar\phi(k) \big).
$$

Comment: I am sorry. I mistakenly read $K \rtimes H$ instead of $H \rtimes K$.

Comment: The question does not make sense because $\bar{\phi}(k)$ is an element of $G/H$ not $K$. But in any case we do not necessarily have $\phi(K)=K$.

Comment: @DerekHolt but $G/H \cong K$. Basically, the question is whether $K$ is characteristic, which as you pointed out is wrong.

Comment: No, $K$ need not be characteristic. For an easy example, take $G=S_3$, $H=\langle (123)\rangle$ (which is characteristic, being the only subgroup of order $3$), and $K=\langle(12)\rangle$. Then $K$ is not characteristic in $G$.

Comment: As pointed out by Holt: you can certainly write: $\varphi(h, kH)=(\varphi(h),\varphi(k)H)$ i.e. $\varphi(h,\overline{k})=(\varphi(h),\varphi(\overline{k}))$ (here action on first component is restriction, and on second one it is by factor automorphism. This seems natural too!)